# How often does iOS monitor for iBeacons?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

I have an iBeacon device I'm working on and am wondering how often iOS monitors/checks/scans for iBeacons when asked to do so via a CoreLocation app? I'm wondering so I know how long to broadcast for my iBeacon is designed to not always be on.

I'm surprised I haven't been able to find this on the web (and of course Apple won't tell us)

Edit: I mean when the app itself is not running because the phone has been restart or the app is shut down.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  IBeacons should always broadcast; how could the beacon know when a device was looking?

Comment: It wouldn't know when a device is looking. I'm building an iBeacon that only broadcasts when a user pushes a button activating it. That's why I'm wondering how often iPhones check for iBeacons - then I can make the iBeacon's firmware broadcast for that amount of time to make sure it gets detected.

Comment: This may help - http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/06/10/beacon-monitoring-in-the-background.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Apple documentation for this, but the following is what I have learned from lots of testing on iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices:

- If the app gets one of the limited (30) bluetooth hardware detection slots, the Bluetooth chip will always be scanning for the beacon pattern.  In theory one packet could trigger the detection, but in practice you may need several seconds of transmission to guarantee detection.
- If the app does not get a hardware acceleration slot, the OS will perform a full scan every 15 minutes.

If you want to target phones that have hardware detection slots, the beacon could transmit for 5 seconds at any time appropriate for the use case.  If you want to target apps without hardware acceleration slots, the beacon must transmit for 15 minutes to guarantee detection.